# Posicionar JCombobox na tela

Tags: java, swing, combobox

Fiz um combo box, no netbeans por comando, e não consigo mudar ele de localização (na frame), os valores do Bounts mudam, mas ele não se move. Já usei todo tipo de comando (setBounds, setPoint, setLocation, etc.).

```
public JComboBox<String> combo_1 = new JComboBox<String>();
public JComboBox<String> combo_2 = new JComboBox<String>();

public Tela(){



    setTitle("Agreste Tour");
    setSize(900,720);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setVisible(true);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("Imagem/Mapa.png"))));
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    setSize(900,720);
    setLayout(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(combo_1);
    add(combo_2);


    combo_1.setName("Origem");
    combo_1.setName("Destino");
    combo_1.setBounds(100, 500, 800, 100);
    System.out.println(""+combo_1.getBounds());


    JButton Okay = new JButton("Mostrar");
    getContentPane().add(Okay);
    Okay.addActionListener(this);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes uma recomendação:

> **Evite usar layout absoluto, a não ser que seja de extrema necessidade e que saiba as consequências disso**, pois layout absoluto dificulta manutenção da tela e faz com que sua aplicação fique com aparência diferente dependendo do monitor e resolução que estiver sendo executada.
>
> Existem vários [**gerenciadores de layouts**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) para que você não tenha que se preocupar com posicionamento ou organização manual de componentes. Sem contar que o uso de layouts faz com que seu código fique mais fácil de dar manutenção do que ficar inserindo um monte de `setbounds`, e caso precise alterar a posição de algum componente, no layout absoluto, vai ter que reposicionar todos manualmente.

Mas mesmo assim quiser insistir em utilizar layout absoluto por sua conta e risco, você não pode definir um layout na tela, e você erroneamente está definindo layout 3 vezes. Remova as seguintes linhas:

```
setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

e

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

deixando apenas `setLayout(null);` que é o que vai anular qualquer tipo de layout e indicará que você vai se responsabilizar pelo posicionamento de tudo na tela.

Outro erro nesse código é esta linha:

```
setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("Imagem/Mapa.png"))));
```

Se você vai usar a tela para adicionar mais componentes, você não pode definir um label como `contentPane`, pois ele não funciona muito bem como um container de outros componentes, e um *ContentPane* representa o container principal de último nivel de um `Frame`(leia mais a respeito [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)), onde todos os outros componentes serão adicionados.

Tem muitos outros erros nesse código que não vou corrigir para não fugir do escopo original da pergunta, mas aconselho a estudar um pouco mais sobre layouts e [java-swing](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info) em si, pois pequenos erros podem gerar uma dor de cabeça tremenda depois que a aplicação já está parcialmente desenvolvida, muitas vezes até pode te forçar a ter que começar tudo de novo.

Comment: Okay, muito obrigado!

Comment: @MarcosNeto se a resposta lhe ajudou, você pode aceitá-la clicando no `v`, assim você marca a pergunta como concluida. :)