# Exibição correta dos RadionButtons

Tags: java, swing

Estou tentando implementar um `JRadioButton` mas após inserir os 2 no formulário, só é exibido um, alguém ajuda por favor ?

```
package com.roknauta.fasttracker.utils;

import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Testes {

    public static JPanel painel = new JPanel();
    private static JFrame formulario = new JFrame();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        formulario.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        formulario.setTitle("dd");
        formulario.setSize(500, 270);
        // Formulário no centro da tela.
        formulario.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        // --[ DESLIGANDO O GERENCIADOR DE LAYOUT ]--\\
        painel.setLayout(null);
        formulario.add(painel);

        // Labels
        final JLabel codigoInicial = new JLabel("Código inicial:");
        final JLabel codigoFinal = new JLabel("Código final:");
        final JLabel ignorarEntregues = new JLabel("Ignorar os já entregues:");

        // JTexts
        final JTextField jL1 = new JTextField();
        final JTextField jL2 = new JTextField();

        final JRadioButton jbY = new JRadioButton("Sim", false);
        final JRadioButton jbN = new JRadioButton("Não", true);

        // Adicionando os componentes
        adiciona(codigoInicial, 10, 10, 100, 25);
        adiciona(jL1, 190, 10, 190, 25);

        adiciona(codigoFinal, 10, 50, 100, 25);
        adiciona(jL2, 190, 50, 190, 25);

        adiciona(ignorarEntregues, 10, 90, 180, 25);
        adiciona(jbY, 190, 90, 190, 25);
        adiciona(jbN, 220, 90, 190, 25);

        formulario.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void adiciona(Component componente, int nColuna, int nLinha, int nLargura, int nAltura) {
        painel.add(componente);
        componente.setBounds(nColuna, nLinha, nLargura, nAltura);
    }
}
```

Fica assim quando executo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como exibir o outro Radio ?

Comment: Forneça um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel executar o código e simular o problema.

Comment: Feito @Articuno

Comment: Por que ta utilizando layout absoluto? É uma pratica ruim a não ser que você saiba o quanto isso dar dor de cabeça, como este seu problema.

Comment: @Articuno estou aprendendo estes Frames ainda....então não sei como resolver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é o fato de você estar utilizando layout absoluto, e esta é uma pratica muito ruim, pois engessa toda a aparencia da sua aplicação ao monitor e resolução que você está desenvolvendo. Sem contar que, se precisar mudar ou adicionar algum componente, terá que mover todos.

O método `setBounds` recebe 4 parametros, sendo eles  a posição horizontal e vertical, a largura e a altura do componente. Deve-se tomar cuidado com isso, pois ao posicionar um componente, você precisa se atentar a onde começa e termina o anterior, e seu componente de radio está sendo inserido abaixo do outro, por isso não está sendo exibido. Isso pode ser observado nestas 2 linhas:

```
adiciona(jbY, 190, 90, 190, 25);
adiciona(jbN, 220, 90, 190, 25);
```

O primeiro radio é posicionado no eixo X na posicao 190 e tem 190px de tamanho. O outro radio é posicionado no eixo X na posicao 220. Repare que o anterior começa em 190 e vai até 190+190, ou seja, o seguinte deveria ser posicionado na posicao 380 do eixo X, e nao em 220.

O que fiz foi reduzir esse tamanho absurdo de radiobutton para apenas 80, fazendo com que ele inicie em 190 indo ate 270, e iniciando o proximo radio ao seu lado, exatamente onde ele termina:

```
adiciona(jbY, 190, 90, 80, 25);
adiciona(jbN, 270, 90, 80, 25);
```

O código final ficou:

```
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JRadioButtonTest {

    public JPanel painel = new JPanel();
    private JFrame formulario = new JFrame();


    public JRadioButtonTest() {
        formulario.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        formulario.setTitle("dd");
        formulario.setSize(500, 270);
        // Formulário no centro da tela.
        formulario.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        // --[ DESLIGANDO O GERENCIADOR DE LAYOUT ]--\\
        painel.setLayout(null);
        formulario.add(painel);

        // Labels
        JLabel codigoInicial = new JLabel("Código inicial:");
        JLabel codigoFinal = new JLabel("Código final:");
        JLabel ignorarEntregues = new JLabel("Ignorar os já entregues:");

        // JTexts
        JTextField jL1 = new JTextField();
        JTextField jL2 = new JTextField();

        JRadioButton jbY = new JRadioButton("Sim", false);
        JRadioButton jbN = new JRadioButton("Não", true);

        // Adicionando os componentes
        adiciona(codigoInicial, 10, 10, 100, 25);
        adiciona(jL1, 190, 10, 190, 25);

        adiciona(codigoFinal, 10, 50, 100, 25);
        adiciona(jL2, 190, 50, 190, 25);

        adiciona(ignorarEntregues, 10, 90, 180, 25);

        adiciona(jbY, 190, 90, 80, 25);
        adiciona(jbN, 270, 90, 80, 25);

        formulario.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new JRadioButtonTest() );
    }

    private void adiciona(Component componente, int nColuna, int nLinha, int nLargura, int nAltura) {
        painel.add(componente);
        componente.setBounds(nColuna, nLinha, nLargura, nAltura);
    }
}
```

Recomendo que leia os links que seguem:

[Por que o método main deve despachar a criação da GUI para a EDT em uma aplicação swing?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2017/28595)

[Formas de despachar a interface para a EDT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193456/28595)

[Evitando utilizar layouts absolutos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/222110/28595)

Comment: Sua resposta antecedeu a minha em alguns segundos e é melhor do que ela. Só recomendaria acrescentar uma parte sobre não usar variáveis estáticas para esse tipo de coisa e daí ela ficaria perfeita.

Comment: Obrigado, eu infelizmente não tenho nenhum conhecimento nestes J. Eu estou fazendo isso apenas como quebra galho já que minha app tava toda dependente de linha de comando e tava ruim pro usuário. Qual o melhor layout pra este meu caso ?

Comment: @Douglas Não existe "o melhor", existe o que mais se adequa a sua situaçao. Da pra fazer essa tela ai com todos os layouts de java tranquilamente, uns vai ser mais complexos, outros pode ser mais simples, é relativo.

Comment: @VictorStafusa opa, vo editar depois com essa informaçao, obrigado :)

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que o botão do "Não" está escondido atrás do botão do "Sim":

```
    adiciona(jbY, 190, 90, 190, 25);
    adiciona(jbN, 220, 90, 190, 25);
```

Essas coordenadas significam que o "Sim" tem 190 pixels de largura, mas o botão do "Não" está apenas 30 pixels mais à direita do que ele. Os 190 pixels de largura do "Sim" são mais que suficientes para ocultar todo o conteúdo do "Não" abaixo dele.

A solução é redefinir as coordenadas:

```
    adiciona(jbY, 190, 90, 100, 25);
    adiciona(jbN, 290, 90, 100, 25);
```

Sugiro também considerar o que há [nessa outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2017/132) e usar o mecanismo lá descrito para não criar a sua tela na thread principal. Manter `JFrame` e `JPanel` em variáveis estáticas também não é uma boa ideia.

Comment: Obrigado, eu peguei este exemplo pronto..rs, eu vou estudar mais esta tecnologia.